# Is Disaster Recovery Turned On?

Tags: ibm-datapower

Where can I check, whether disaster recovery is turned on/off on a XI52 DataPower Appliance?

Comment: I agree, this question is off topic for stackoverflow. Any suggestions, which forum is more appropriate? I just posted the question here, because it features an "ibm-datapower" tag :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `show system` from CLI and check `backup mode` property. Also you can use WebGUI `Administration->Device->System Settings`

> xi50(config)# show system
>
> ```
>   product id: 92354BX [Rev 01]
>          OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.14685.1.3
>       uptime: 105 days 10:39:08
>      contact: contact
>         name: XXXXXXX
>     location: Location
>     services: 72
>  backup mode: secure
> product mode: normal
> ```